# Uncaught ReferenceError: CodeMirror is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, codemirror

I am trying to include CodeMirror Plugin but am getting this error
Uncaught ReferenceError: CodeMirror is not defined

My HTML CODE is here

http://pastie.org/4673008

Can anyone help ??

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're loading the clike module before CodeMirror itself.

Change the order in your HTML head from this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../CodeMirror-2.33/mode/clike/clike.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../CodeMirror-2.33/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../CodeMirror-2.33/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
```

To this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../CodeMirror-2.33/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../CodeMirror-2.33/mode/clike/clike.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../CodeMirror-2.33/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am facing similar issue and I have posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69430941/7584240 If you get a chance can you please have a look and provide some resolution.

Answer (score 0):

`ngx-codemirror` SQL high-late is not working, deeper I found the to the code mirror tag the class to high-late syntax cm-default, cm-link, cm-keyword these class is not appending.
config used : 
public queryConfig = {
        lineNumbers: true,
        theme: 'twilight',
        mode: 'text/x-sql',
        lineWrapping : true,
        autoFocus: true
    };

The `main.ts` file added the imports below:

[image: main.ts scripts]

The `angularcli.json` file added the scripts below:

[image: angularcli.json scripts]

Comment: issue resolved by adding the "matchBrackets:true" to the query config like below,

queryConfig = { lineNumbers: true, theme: 'twilight', matchBrackets:true, mode: 'text/x-sql', lineWrapping : true, autoFocus: true };

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am facing a similar issue and I have posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69430941/7584240 If you get a chance can you please have a look and provide some resolution.